# Auto download attachment PDF file with particular subject from a shared Outlook mailbox

Tags: vba, outlook

is there any way to auto download attached pdf file from shared outlook mailbox to local folder using vba coding?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [SaveAsFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Attachment.SaveAsFile) method of the Attachment class which saves the attachment to the specified path.

```
Sub SaveAttachment() 
 Dim myInspector As Outlook.Inspector  
 Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem 
 Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments 
 
 Set myInspector = Application.ActiveInspector  
 If Not TypeName(myInspector) = "Nothing" Then  
 If TypeName(myInspector.CurrentItem) = "MailItem" Then  
 Set myItem = myInspector.CurrentItem  
 Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments  
 'Prompt the user for confirmation  
 Dim strPrompt As String 
 
 strPrompt = "Are you sure you want to save the first attachment in the current item to the Documents folder? If a file with the same name already exists in the destination folder, it will be overwritten with this copy of the file."  
 If MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then  
 myAttachments.Item(1).SaveAsFile Environ("HOMEPATH") & "\My Documents\" & _  
 myAttachments.Item(1).DisplayName  
 End If  
 Else  
 MsgBox "The item is of the wrong type."  
 End If  
 End If  
End Sub
```

To find all items with a specific string in the subject line you need to use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class. Read more about them in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Use the [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder) method to get a shared folder. It returns a `Folder` object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. For example, the following VBA example uses the `GetSharedDefaultFolder` method to resolve the `Recipient` object representing Eugene, and then returns Eugene's shared default Calendar folder:

```
Sub ResolveName()  
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace  
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient  
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 

 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")  
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Eugene Astafiev")  
 myRecipient.Resolve  
 If myRecipient.Resolved Then  
  Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)  
 End If  
End Sub 
  
Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)  
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 
 Set CalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar)  
 CalendarFolder.Display  
End Sub
```